# how to customise the fontsize of a label for quiver reference vector

Tags: python, plot, label, latitude-longitude, font-size

I am new to python and I am Plotting moisture flux. I am displaying quiverkey and I cannot able to decrease the fontsize of my label for my quiver reference vector. My problem is not in the length of quiver refererence vector but the font size of it's labeling. I cant adjust it by putting 'fontsize=10'. Then there is an error. I think quiverkey donot have a attribute fontsize. I am displaying my code here.

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import cartopy.crs as ccrs
import matplotlib.ticker as mticker
d1=xr.open_dataset('ucomp_2018daily.nc')
uf=d1.u
vf=d3.v
qf=d5.q
qf=qf*1000
lon=d1.lon
lat=d1.lat
lev=np.arange(5,250,45)
fig=plt.figure(figsize=(15,2),facecolor="w")
for k in range (7):
    level=['1e+05','9.25e+04', '8.5e+04', '7e+04', '6e+04', '5e+04', '4e+04']#
    qfd=qf.resample(time='1D').mean().sel(plev=(level[k]))
    ufd=uf.resample(time='1D').mean().sel(plev=(level[k]))
    vfd=vf.resample(time='1D').mean().sel(plev=(level[k]))
    sdate='2018-08-08'
    edate='2018-08-17'
    qfds=qfd*qfd
    ufds=ufd*ufd
    vfds=vfd*vfd
    magf=np.sqrt((qfds*ufds)+(qfds*vfds))
    ax=fig.add_subplot(1,7,k+1,projection=ccrs.PlateCarree())
    ax.gridlines(linewidth=0,color='None',linestyle=':')
    gl.xlabel_style={'size':10}
    gl.ylabel_style={'size':10}
    sh=plt.contourf(lon,lat,magf[:,:],cmap=plt.cm.GnBu,levels=lev, extend='both')
    gl.xlocator=mticker.FixedLocator([60,70,80,90,100])#for setting the tickfrequency=10
    gl.yloctor=mticker.FixedLocator([-10,0,10,20,30,40])
    qu=ax.quiver(lon[::10],lat[::10],qfds*ufds[::10,::10],qfds*vfds[::10,::10],width=0.003)
scalef=None
cbar=fig.colorbar(sh,cax=fig.add_axes([0.12,0.0605,0.8,0.060]),orientation='horizontal')
cbar.ax.tick_params(labelsize=10)
cbar.ax.set_title('kg/ms', fontsize=10)
ax.quiverkey(qu,X=0.9,Y=1.18,U=100,label='100kg/ms',labelpos='W')
```

Comment: if you are asking about plotting with `matplotlib` when reduce the question to a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score 0):

add fontproperties option to your quiverkey function

```
ax.quiverkey(qu,X=0.9,Y=1.18,U=100,label='100kg/ms',labelpos='W', fontproperties={'size':18})
```